# Replacing a text box with DateChooserCombo in org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData

Tags: java, eclipse, datagrid, swt, dynamic-controls

I had dialog created in SWT using GridData having:

Label1: ComboBox
Label2: TextBox1
Label3: TextBox2

checkbox1  Label4
checkbox2  Label5

Based on the ComoBox selected value, I need to replace TextBox2 with DateChooserCombo or DateChooserCombo with TextBox2.

Below is my class implementation with method createTextBox that create TextBox2 when loading the dialog. The setDatePicker called on change of Combo Box value. Please provide assistance on implementation in below Class on how can we achieve it. Thanks in advance.

```
public class ConfgElementInsertDialog extends DialogEx {
    private Text typeName;
    private Text defaultValueText;
    private Combo templateType;
    private Button isKeyCheckBox;
    private Button isEditableCheckBox;
    private Button toDisplayCheckBox;
    private Button okButton;
    private boolean isInstanceConfig;
    private List<String> configElementName;
    private boolean isKey = false;
    private boolean toDisplay = false;
    private boolean isEditable = false;
    private String label;
    private String name;
    private String defaultVal;
    private boolean isEdit;
    private Text configElementNameText;
    private List<String> dateItem = Arrays.asList("effectiveDate", "endDate", "premiumEffectiveDate ","premiumEndDate");
    private boolean isDatePicker;
    private Date defaulDatetVal;
    DateChooserCombo enumDateChooser;
    Group templateTypeGroup;


    public ConfgElementInsertDialog (Shell shell) {
        super(shell);
        setShellStyle(getShellStyle() | SWT.RESIZE);
    }

    public ConfgElementInsertDialog (Shell shell, boolean isInstanceconfig,
            boolean isEdit) {
        super(shell);
        this.isInstanceConfig = isInstanceconfig;
        this.isEdit = isEdit;
        setShellStyle(getShellStyle() | SWT.RESIZE);
    }

    protected void configureShell(Shell shell) {
        super.configureShell(shell);
        shell.setSize(300, 300);
        if (!isEdit)
            shell.setText(TableTemplateConfigConstants.ADD_CONFIG_DIALOG);
        else
            shell.setText(TableTemplateConfigConstants.EDIT_CONFIG_DIALOG);

    }

    protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
        Composite child = new Composite(parent, SWT.FILL);
        child.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
        child.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        templateTypeGroup = new Group(child, SWT.FILL);
        templateTypeGroup.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true,
                true));
        templateTypeGroup.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, false));

        GridData data = new GridData(SWT.None, SWT.FILL, false, false, 2, 1);
        data.widthHint = 100;
        if(isInstanceConfig)
            templateTypeGroup.setText(TableTemplateConfigConstants.ADD_CONFIG_GROUP_INSTANCE_TEXT);
        else
            templateTypeGroup.setText(TableTemplateConfigConstants.ADD_CONFIG_GROUP_TEMPLATE_TEXT);

        Label label1 = new Label(templateTypeGroup, SWT.NULL);
        label1.setText(TableTemplateConfigConstants.NAME_LABEL);
        if (!isEdit) {
            templateType = new Combo(templateTypeGroup, SWT.V_SCROLL);
            templateType.setLayoutData(data);

            templateType.setItems(getConfigElementName().toArray(
                    new String[getConfigElementName().size()]));
            templateType.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                    if (templateType.getSelection() != null
                            && !templateType.getItem(templateType.getSelectionIndex()).isEmpty()) {
                        setName(templateType.getItem(templateType.getSelectionIndex()));                        
                        setDatePicker(templateType.getItem(templateType.getSelectionIndex()),templateTypeGroup);
                        okButton.setEnabled(true);
                    } else
                        okButton.setEnabled(false);

                }
            });
        } else {
            configElementNameText = new Text(templateTypeGroup, SWT.BORDER);
            configElementNameText.setLayoutData(data);
            configElementNameText.setEnabled(false);
            if(getName()!=null){
            configElementNameText.setText(getName());
            setName(getName());
            setDatePicker(getName(),templateTypeGroup);
            }
        }

        Label label = new Label(templateTypeGroup, SWT.NULL);
        label.setText(TableTemplateConfigConstants.LABEL_TEXT);

        typeName = new Text(templateTypeGroup, SWT.BORDER);
        typeName.setLayoutData(data);
        typeName.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {

            @Override
            public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {
                setLabel(typeName.getText());

            }
        });


        createTextBox(templateTypeGroup, data);

//      }
        isKeyCheckBox = new Button(templateTypeGroup, SWT.CHECK);
        isKeyCheckBox.setText(TableTemplateConfigConstants.REQUIRED_LABEL);
        isKeyCheckBox.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true,
                true, 1, 1));

        isKeyCheckBox.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                if (isKeyCheckBox.getSelection())
                    setKey(true);
                else
                    setKey(false);
            }
        });

        isEditableCheckBox = new Button(templateTypeGroup, SWT.CHECK);
        isEditableCheckBox.setSelection(true);
        if (!isEdit)
            setEditable(true);
        if(getDefaultVal()==null || getDefaultVal().isEmpty())
            {isEditableCheckBox.setEnabled(false);

            }
        isEditableCheckBox.setText(TableTemplateConfigConstants.EDITABLE_LABEL);
        isEditableCheckBox.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true,
                true, 1, 1));
        isEditableCheckBox.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                if (isEditableCheckBox.getSelection())
                    setEditable(true);
                else
                    setEditable(false);
            }
        });

        if (!isInstanceConfig) {
            toDisplayCheckBox = new Button(templateTypeGroup, SWT.CHECK);
            toDisplayCheckBox.setSelection(true);
            if(getDefaultVal()==null || getDefaultVal().isEmpty())
                toDisplayCheckBox.setEnabled(false);
            toDisplayCheckBox.setText(TableTemplateConfigConstants.DISPLAY_LABEL);
            toDisplayCheckBox.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL,
                    true, true, 1, 1));
            toDisplayCheckBox.setSelection(true);
            if (!isEdit)
                setToDisplay(true);
            toDisplayCheckBox.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                    if (toDisplayCheckBox.getSelection())
                        setToDisplay(true);
                    else
                        setToDisplay(false);
                }
            });
            if (isEdit) {
                toDisplayCheckBox.setSelection(isToDisplay());
            }
        }
        if (isEdit) {
            isKeyCheckBox.setSelection(isKey());
            if(getLabel()!=null)
            typeName.setText(getLabel());
            if(getDefaultVal()!=null)
                defaultValueText.setText(getDefaultVal());
            isEditableCheckBox.setSelection(isEditable());
        }
        return child;
    }

    protected void createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite parent) {
        super.createButtonsForButtonBar(parent);
        okButton = getButton(IDialogConstants.OK_ID);
        if(isEdit)
            okButton.setEnabled(true);
        else
        okButton.setEnabled(false);
    }

    public List<String> getConfigElementName() {
        return configElementName;
    }

    public void setConfigElementName(List<String> configElementName) {
        this.configElementName = configElementName;
    }

    public boolean isKey() {
        return isKey;
    }

    public void setKey(boolean isKey) {
        this.isKey = isKey;
    }

    public boolean isToDisplay() {
        return toDisplay;
    }

    public void setToDisplay(boolean toDisplay) {
        this.toDisplay = toDisplay;
    }

    public boolean isEditable() {
        return isEditable;
    }

    public void setEditable(boolean isEditable) {
        this.isEditable = isEditable;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getDefaultVal() {
        return defaultVal;
    }

    public void setDefaultVal(String defaultVal) {
        this.defaultVal = defaultVal;
    }

    public List<String> getListForDatePickere() {
        return dateItem;
    }

    public void setDatePicker(String value, Group templateTypeGroup) {
        if(dateItem.contains(value) && null != defaultValueText){
            Object grd = defaultValueText.getLayoutData();
            defaultValueText.dispose();
            defaultValueText = null;
            createDateControl(templateTypeGroup,grd);
        }else if(!dateItem.contains(value) && null != enumDateChooser){
            Object grd = enumDateChooser.getLayoutData();
            enumDateChooser.dispose();
            enumDateChooser = null;
            createTextBox(templateTypeGroup,enumDateChooser.getLayoutData());
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the defaulDatetVal
     */
    public Date getDefaulDatetVal() {
        return defaulDatetVal;
    }

    /**
     * @param defaulDatetVal the defaulDatetVal to set
     */
    public void setDefaulDatetVal(Date defaulDatetVal) {
        this.defaulDatetVal = defaulDatetVal;
    }

    public void createTextBox(Composite templateTypeGroup, Object data){
        Label defaultLabel = new Label(templateTypeGroup, SWT.NULL);
        defaultLabel.setText(TableTemplateConfigConstants.DEFAULT_VAL_TEXT);

        defaultValueText = new Text(templateTypeGroup, SWT.BORDER);
        defaultValueText.setLayoutData(data);
        defaultValueText.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {

            @Override
            public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {
                setDefaultVal(defaultValueText.getText());
                if(!isEdit && (defaultValueText.getText()==null || defaultValueText.getText().isEmpty()))
                {
                    setToDisplay(true);
                    toDisplayCheckBox.setSelection(true);
                    toDisplayCheckBox.setEnabled(false);
                    setEditable(true);
                    isEditableCheckBox.setSelection(true);
                    isEditableCheckBox.setEnabled(false);

                }
                if(!isEdit && (defaultValueText.getText()!=null && !defaultValueText.getText().isEmpty()))
                {
                    isEditableCheckBox.setEnabled(true);
                    toDisplayCheckBox.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void createDateControl(Composite templateTypeGroup, Object data){
        Label defaultLbl = new Label(templateTypeGroup, SWT.NULL);
        defaultLbl.setText(TableTemplateConfigConstants.DEFAULT_VAL_TEXT);
        enumDateChooser = new DateChooserCombo(
                templateTypeGroup, SWT.BORDER | CDT.DROP_DOWN
                        | CDT.DATE_SHORT);
        enumDateChooser.setFormatter(new DateFormatter(
                ITableDataConstants.DATE_FORMAT_TABLE_VIEWER));
        enumDateChooser.setValue(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        enumDateChooser.setLayoutData((GridData)data);
        enumDateChooser.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {

            @Override
            public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {

                setDefaulDatetVal(enumDateChooser.getValue());
                if(!isEdit && (enumDateChooser.getValue()==null))
                {
                    setToDisplay(true);
                    toDisplayCheckBox.setSelection(true);
                    toDisplayCheckBox.setEnabled(false);
                    setEditable(true);
                    isEditableCheckBox.setSelection(true);
                    isEditableCheckBox.setEnabled(false);

                }
                if(!isEdit && (defaultValueText.getText()!=null && !defaultValueText.getText().isEmpty()))
                {
                    isEditableCheckBox.setEnabled(true);
                    toDisplayCheckBox.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: And what's not working with the code you have just now?

Comment: In above code like to have implementation on how can we replace TextBox2 with DateChooserCombo or DateChooserCombo with TextBox2. Above code not doing the proper replacment. I had done few POC and seems getting know the right result. Which I will share with you all soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented method on selection change event of combo box i.e. setControl(templateType.getItem(templateType.getSelectionIndex()),templateTypeGroup);

it take layout and display details before disposing old control and create a new control by passing details of old controls.

```
public void setControl(String value, Group templateTypeGroup) {
    Object grd = null;
    Point pt = null;
    Rectangle rct = null;   
    if(TableTemplateConfigConstants.dateItems.contains(value) && null != defaultValueText){
        grd = defaultValueText.getLayoutData();
        pt = defaultValueText.getLocation();
        rct = defaultValueText.getBounds();
        defaultValueText.dispose();
        cleanControls();
        createDateControl(templateTypeGroup,grd,pt,rct,value);}}


public void createDateControl(Composite templateTypeGroup, Object data, Point pt, Rectangle rectangle,String value){
    **enumDateChooser = new DateChooserCombo(
            templateTypeGroup, SWT.BORDER | CDT.DROP_DOWN
                    | CDT.DATE_SHORT);
    enumDateChooser.setFormatter(new DateFormatter(
            ITableDataConstants.DATE_FORMAT_TABLE_VIEWER));     
    enumDateChooser.setLayoutData((GridData)data);
    if(null != pt && null != rectangle){
        enumDateChooser.setLocation(pt);
        enumDateChooser.setBounds(rectangle);
    }
    enumDateChooser.setLocation(pt)**
    try {
    if(!isEdit){    


        if (TableTemplateConfigConstants.endDateLst.contains(value)) {
            enumDateChooser
                    .setValue(checkFormat(TableTemplateConfigConstants.endDate));
            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(TableTemplateConfigConstants.DATE_FORMAT_TABLE_VIEWER); 
            setDefaultVal(formatter.format(checkFormat(enumDateChooser.getText())));
        } else if (TableTemplateConfigConstants.effectiveDate
                .contains(value)) {
            enumDateChooser.setValue(new Date());
            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(TableTemplateConfigConstants.DATE_FORMAT_TABLE_VIEWER); 
            setDefaultVal(formatter.format(checkFormat(enumDateChooser.getText())));
        } else if (null != getDefaultVal() && !getDefaultVal().isEmpty()) {
            enumDateChooser.setValue(checkFormat(getDefaultVal()));
            setDefaultVal(value);
        }
    }else{
        enumDateChooser
        .setValue(checkFormat(getDefaultVal()));
    }
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        PALogger.logError("Unable to parse date",
                PAEventCategory.OTHERS, Activator.PLUGIN_ID,e1);
    }

    setDateDecoration(false);
    enumDateChooser.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {

        @Override
        public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {             
            System.out.println(enumDateChooser.getText());
            if (null != enumDateChooser && !enumDateChooser.isDisposed()
                    ) {
                setDateDecoration(true);
            }
            setDateCheckBoxes();
        }
    });
}
```